# AngularJS and papaParse Integration

Tags: angularjs, papaparse

My form is this

```
<form name="form-basic" class="form-validation" ng-submit="uploadFile(updFrm.file)">
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="filee" id="files" ng-model="updFrm.file"/>
<input type="submit" value="click" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

I want to Pass Value of Input "file" into papaParse

```
Papa.parse(fileInput.files[0], {
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

Now how to replace fileInput.files[0] with Value from "    `<input type="file" class="form-control" id="files" ng-model="updFrm.file"/>`"

Please guide...

Comment: I made it work by using this
`
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
    x = document.getElementsByName("filee")[0].files[0];
    // console.log($('#files')[0].files);
    Papa.parse(x, {
        complete: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
        }
    });
        
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change `$scope.updFrm.file` instead of `fileInput.files[0]`

//Or

in your function via

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(fileDetails)
{
  Papa.parse(fileDetails, {
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: Sorry it gives error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'stream' of null
    at Object.t [as parse] (papaparse.min.js:6)
    at ChildScope.$scope.uploadFile

Comment: just try `fileDetails[0]` instead of `fileDetails`

Comment: Sorry !!
Error
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.uploadFile

Comment: Actually i m successful in getting data from local file.... 
`   $('#files').parse({
    config: config,
    before: function(file, inputElem)
    {
     console.log("Parsing file:", file);
                    $scope.updAllow = true;
    },
    complete: function()
    {
     console.log("Done with all files.");
                    
    }
   });`
But i m not getting to pass on the value INTO SCOPE of Angular